# Swift sending and recieving array between two phones

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, send

I want to create an app that sends an array (of integers and strings) to a friend, allows them to view and edit the array, and then send the new array back. What methods or SDKs would allow me to do that? Do I have to create a server? If so, how do I create a server and communicate with it?

Note: The two devices will be nowhere near each other, so using Multipeerconnectivity will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need a server, but you don't have to build it yourself. Parse.com has a great SDK for this and [here](http://attila.tumblr.com/post/21180235691/ios-tutorial-creating-a-chat-room-using-parse-com) is a tutorial for building a chat room app that would be a good starting point.

Comment: The only problem with that is that it's not swift. Thanks for the Parse.com though.

Comment: The tutorial will show you which Parse API to use. They are the same in Swift and Objective-C.